# Secure Cookie Issue: Cookies only secure sometimes

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies

I am trying to secure the cookies returned from my ASP.NET application.

I set requireSSL="true" my web.config but it looks like the cookies are only secure sometimes. I will check the request in Firebug or Chrome dev tools and the cookie will be secure sometimes (it look like it is usually the first time I visit the page but subsequent visits they are not secure).

Screen shot of Chrome dev tools: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i7qU.png

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Thanks for the help!

**Web.Config Settings**

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: That looks correct. Are there any other applications on the server? All there any other servers in the cluster where this setting has been missed?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is a single server configuration, so this isn't a miss configured load balance scenario. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you need any further help with this? Let me know and I'll update my answer if so.

Answer (score 2):

It could well be working.

Chrome dev tools only show cookies marked as HTTP Only and Secure in the Response and not the Request, so your setup might be working. It seems like it could be a bug in Chrome dev tools or that it is only showing what is provided in the request (the fact that they are secure or HTTP only is not indicated in an actual HTTP request, only the value is sent to the server). Either way I think it should show `N/A` in these columns to show that they do not apply to HTTP requests.

To verify that your cookie has been set correctly you could try the [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) extension. This will indicate for each cookie whether it has the `Secure` or `HTTP Only` attributes applied.

Answer (score 0):

can you please elaborate what you mean by secure ? if sslonly flag is set then offcourse all cookies will be sent over encrypted connection only.  but that doesn't prevent you from seeing in debugger

Comment: The issue is that not I see the values in the debugger. My concern is that the values are not returned with the secure flag all the time. It seems like the first time it is returned secure but not all the subsequent times.