# PHP session.cookie_secure does not actually set the cookie to secure

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

In my `php.ini` confirmed I have:

```
session.cookie_secure = 1
```

Also, doing:

```
<?php print_r(session_get_cookie_params()); ?>
```

Results in:

```
Array ( [lifetime] => 0 [path] => / [domain] => [secure] => 1 [httponly] => 1 )
```

However, inspecting a page in my application with Chrome Developer tools, going to cookies, it lists that sessions cookie is **not** secure, and not http only.

[image]
[image]

Comment: if you just switched from non secure config to secure, make sure to delete the old cookie or else it will be used with old non secure settings.

Comment: Nope still showing as not secure, and not http only.

Comment: Do you request it via HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my [answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20345615/413180), Chrome developer tools always show blank `Secure` and `HTTP` attributes when the cookie is sent in the request. This is because the fact that a cookie is secure or HTTP only is not actually sent in a HTTP request. All that is sent is the name/value pair in the `Cookie` HTTP request header:

`Cookie: name=value`

Try an extension such as [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) which will show whether the cookie has been successfully set as secure and HTTP Only.